# How to get 5 LEVEL hierarchy users from database using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I want to fetch the child user ID based on the parent ID. I have found a solution
[how to count members in 15 level deep for each level in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444391/how-to-count-members-in-15-level-deep-for-each-level-in-php)
Tried Answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535568/23864372
but am getting some errors.

I have created a class -

```
<?php 
Class Team extends Database { 

 private $dbConnection;

 function __construct($db)
 {
  $this->dbConnection = $db;
 }

 public function getDownline($id, $depth=5) {

        $stack = array($id);
        for($i=1; $i<=$depth; $i++) {

            // create an array of levels, each holding an array of child ids for that level
            $stack[$i] = $this->getChildren($stack[$i-1]);
        }

        return $stack;
    }

    public function countLevel($level) {

         // expects an array of child ids
         settype($level, 'array');

         return sizeof($level);
    }

    private function getChildren($parent_ids = array()) {

        $result = array();
        $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($parent_ids) - 1). '?'; 
        $sql="select id from users where pid in ($placeholders)";
        $stmt=$this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($parent_ids));

        while($row=$stmt->fetch()) {

            $results[] = $row->id;
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

I am using the class like this -

```
$id = 1;
$depth = 2;  // get the counts of his downline, only 2 deep.
$downline_array = $getTeam->getDownline($id, $depth=2);
```

I am getting errors -
In line

```
  $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($parent_ids) - 1). '?';
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be
> of type Countable|array, int given in

and second

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
> number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
> line

```
$sql="select id from users where pid in ($placeholders)";
        $stmt=$this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
```

I want to fetch the child user ID in 5 levels .
PHP VERSION 8.1

Database table

```
superheroes
       -----------
id   parent_id   name
1    0           Steven Rogers
2    1           Bruce Banner
3    1           Wally West
4    2           Peter Parker
5    2           Jay Garrick
6    4           Barry Allen
7    4           Reed Richards
```

Comment: `I am creating an MLM (multi-level marketing) system`... Oh, [lucky us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_marketing#Comparisons_to_pyramid_schemes) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the errors, but you've missed off the bit where it tells you which line of code threw the errors. Please clarify that for us, then we can be sure exactly where things are going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading, the reason for my first comment is visible [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78237753/revisions)

Comment: Please check again. I updated the code lines.

Comment: Ok so the first error is because during a call to `getChildren` you're passing in something which isn't array as the `$parent_ids` value. You need to do some simple debugging to find out why that is, and on which iteration it's happening. The second error is simply a consequence of the first.

Comment: `$result = array();` is a typo - it should probably be `$results = array();`. Your issue might be as simple as that: because in cases where there are no children, it will return `$results` which will be undefined, whereas presumably it was supposed to return an empty array. I'm surprised you don't have warning messages about this anyway when you try to add to the array in the loop - have you supressed warning messages in your PHP configuration? Or are you maybe using an out of date PHP version? See [PHP Supported Versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: ...also if you use a good IDE it should warn you about undefined variables before you even run the code.

Comment: I changed  $results= array();  but first I'm getting error in this line $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($parent_ids) - 1). '?';   and not getting the solution.

Comment: OK well that fixes one possible cause. Now like I said you have to debug and find out where it still feeds the wrong data. We can't see your data so we can't do that for you. I assume you understand how to do basic debugging of your code

Comment: I just added database table in question description .

Comment: https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP, if you're not familiar with the concept

Comment: Here you go: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/431280e176462b7e8001fab0f5b483e6/php/php81/51e17c3ee36ea19e88de158e228782cd/ . It crashes on the very first run because the very first value you pass into `getChildren` is `1`, which (obviously) isn't an array

Comment: Once you fix that, there are a couple of other minor issues as well. Here's a version which runs without crashing: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/431280e176462b7e8001fab0f5b483e6/php/php81/e22e981727ccf23c655b5dbc2160c3d6/ . You'll have to check if the output is what you expected.

Comment: getChildren($stack[$i-1]); passing $stack array in getChildren method and already stored $id value in   $stack = array($id);  $stack() that is array .

Comment: `that is array`...yes, but when you write `$stack[$i-1]` then it takes one value _out_ of that array, and that value from within the array is just `1`, the first time you run it. I proved it in the first demo. Hence why my solution involves putting an inner array inside that one too - did you look at the two demos?

Comment: `getChildren($stack[$i-1]); passing $stack array`...no. As I said, it's passing one item from within the array. Big difference.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few small problems:

- `$result = array();` is a typo and should be `$results = array();`
- `$stack = array($id);` needs to be `$stack = array([$id]);` because when you write `$stack[$i-1]` then it takes one value out of that array, and without this change that value from within the array is just `1`, the first time you run the code.
- `$results[] = $row->id;` should be `$results[] = $row["id"];` because you are fetching rows as arrays from the database, not as objects.

Here's the rewritten class:

```
Class Team extends Database { 

 private $dbConnection;

 function __construct($db)
 {
  $this->dbConnection = $db;
 }

 public function getDownline($id, $depth=5) {

        $stack = array([$id]);
        for($i=1; $i<=$depth; $i++) {

            // create an array of levels, each holding an array of child ids for that level
            $stack[$i] = $this->getChildren($stack[$i-1]);
        }

        return $stack;
    }

    public function countLevel($level) {

         // expects an array of child ids
         settype($level, 'array');

         return sizeof($level);
    }

    private function getChildren($parent_ids = array()) {

        $results = array();
        $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($parent_ids) - 1). '?'; 
        $sql="select id from users where pid in ($placeholders)";
        $stmt=$this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($parent_ids);

        while($row=$stmt->fetch()) {

            $results[] = $row["id"];
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/431280e176462b7e8001fab0f5b483e6/php/php81/e22e981727ccf23c655b5dbc2160c3d6/